# Some grid tile didn't get features when I using tileStrategy in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, vector, tiles, features

Question updated at 2023-05-26.

Context: Use ol/layer/Vector and ol/source/Vector.js to display my features.

Following is my vector source:

```
const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  loader: function (extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
    var lonLatExtent = transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    console.log(lonLatExtent);
    const dx = lonLatExtent[2] - lonLatExtent[0];
    const dy = lonLatExtent[3] - lonLatExtent[1];
    const lon = (lonLatExtent[0] + lonLatExtent[2]) / 2;
    const lat = (lonLatExtent[1] + lonLatExtent[3]) / 2;
    const feature1 = new Feature(new Point(fromLonLat([lon, lat])));
    const feature2 = new Feature(new Polygon([[
      fromLonLat([lonLatExtent[0] + dx / 10, lonLatExtent[1] + dy / 10]),
      fromLonLat([lonLatExtent[0] + dx / 10, lonLatExtent[3] - dy / 10]),
      fromLonLat([lonLatExtent[2] - dx / 10, lonLatExtent[3] - dy / 10]),
      fromLonLat([lonLatExtent[2] - dx / 10, lonLatExtent[1] + dy / 10]),
      fromLonLat([lonLatExtent[0] + dx / 10, lonLatExtent[1] + dy / 10])
    ]]));
    const features = [feature1, feature2];
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    success(features);
  },
  strategy: tileStrategy(
    createXYZ({
      tileSize: 512,
    })
  )
});

const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: (function () {
    var style1 = new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#FF0000',
        width: 1
      }),
      text: new Text({
        text: 'Hello',
        scale: 1.3,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#000000'
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#FFFF99',
          width: 3.5
        })
      })
    });
    var style2 = new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#FF0000',
        width: 1
      }),
      text: new Text({
        text: '',
        scale: 1.3,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#000000'
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#00FF00',
          width: 3.5
        })
      })
    });
    return function (feature, resolution) {
      const geom = feature.getGeometry();
      if (geom instanceof Point) {
        const corordinates = geom.getCoordinates();
        var lonlat = transform(corordinates, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
        console.log("Point lon lat: ", lonlat);
        style1.getText().setText(lonlat[0].toFixed(4) + "," + lonlat[1].toFixed(4));
        return [style1];
      }
      if (geom instanceof Polygon) {
        const corordinates = geom.getFirstCoordinate();
        console.log("Corordinates of Polygon: ", corordinates);
        return [style2];
      }
    };
  })()
});
```

In the loader function, I generate a point in the center of the extent and a rectangle in the extent.

And following is what I get:

[image]

Seems it works fine.

However, when I zoom in, this is what I get.

[image]

In zoom 2, loader function was called for some tile, and not called for some other tiles.

Why?

Comment: It does not reload extents which have already been loaded as part of a larger extent.  If you want to load only small extents set a `minZoom` on the grid in `createXYZ`.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for you reply. But when I zoom in, some of extents get new features even though a extend including it already been loaded. I pasted the image in my question.